# Google Street View Image Date

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

Is there a way to access the date an image on Google Street View was taken? This [was presented on the webpage](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-maps-images-dated-14728.html) on previous iterations, but now appears to be gone. This data doesn't appear to be accessible via the Google Street View API.

Answer (score 2):

These details may be accessed via the [**`StreetViewService`** of the Maps-JS-API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#StreetViewService).

The returned [**`StreetViewPanoramaData`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#StreetViewPanoramaData) contains a property `imageDate` with the desired information.